# Deploying Java Application on Heroku database postgres configuration issue

Tags: java, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am new to Heroku and have a couple of doubts regarding the database configurations :

I was able to successfully copy the default person template project (that is present on heroku)on to my local machine and wish to know where are the beans are mapped to the entities on the database.

I was expecting a mapping and configuration files that are generally mentioned in spring hibernate project hbm.xml and hbm.cfg.

But, I don't see any configuration or mapping files in the default template that is created. All that I see is some database login credentials in the applicationconext.xml but any bean names and attributes.

Now, I wish to add more classes and more services to this existing template.But am not sure how to map the beans to the entities.Could some one please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example code?
If it's using hibernate and there are no hbm.xml files, it's likely that it's using Annotations.

Comment: here it is (link)[http://damp-plains-3713.herokuapp.com/] ... if u r not able to check the code .could you please provide me ur mail id so that i can give u the access to the code on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working from the Java/Spring template (found on Github here: https://github.com/heroku/template-java-spring-hibernate). @GrayBeardedGeek is correct that the project uses Hibernate (JPA) annotations instead of Hibernate config files. You can find many comprehensive tutorials (google 'hibernate annotation tutorial'), but the gist is that the class/property declarations in the XML are replaced by Java annotations (`@Entity`, `@Column`, `@OneToMany`, etc.) directly on the persistent objects.

Look at the `src/main/java/com/example/model/Person.java` file from the project as a starting point; you'll see the `@Entity` annotation, as well as the `@Id` to specify the primary key. The field/column mappings are otherwise inferred.

Hope this helps.